# HTTP post request with json and okhttp3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, http-post, okhttp

Im trying to make a post request using the okhttp3 library, but I keep getting an internal error. I am new to using this library and android studio, but every recourse I have looked at has the post request set up like this. Am I doing the request wrong and if so is there anyway to fix it?

```
package com.example.john.okhttp;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnSendHttpRequest;
    private EditText etJsonResponse;
    private TextView View;
    private TextView View2;
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
    private Request request ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //set button and text view values
        btnSendHttpRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendRequest);
        View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view1) ;
        View2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        etJsonResponse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etjson);
        //response for button
        btnSendHttpRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //http request
                new Requesting().execute();
            }
        });

    }


    public class Requesting extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String>
    {
        // post request stuff
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            // get client
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            //post method to post to server
            String url = "http://45.55.92.243/newuser";
            String json = "{ 'id' : 333333, 'name' : john }";


            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            try(Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()){
                return response.body().string();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("section1");
                return null;
            }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String retstr) {
        super.onPostExecute(retstr);
        //rewrite text view
        try {
            // create json ob from response
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(retstr);
            //get the values from the json key value pairs
            String id = jsonObj.toString();
            //update the text views
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
            textView.setText(id);
            System.out.println(retstr);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(retstr);
            System.out.println("section2");
        }
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion,you should read the demo of the okhttp3,and you need not use AsyncTask with okhttp3,in these libraries,thread will be created!You just need register a callback to listen the result of the network!

Comment: I do plan on taking that out but do you think that is why I'm getting this problem? I just found out my server is getting the request but the json package is cumming up as empty.

Comment: Oh,please use TextUtils(in the package of android.text) to make sure that the result of server is not empty!

Comment: Why not use the Volley Library ? It handles everything for you and is quite fast as well. Check it out.

Comment: That is not very helpful. If you can't help please refrain from posting void answers.